# Как красиво сделать один метода на все типы целых чисел?

Tags: java

Как красиво написать метод, чтобы в него можно было передавать любой целочисленный тип (byte, short, int, long) чтобы с числом, независимо от типа, делалась пара несложных математический операций?

Comment: Ну, например написать перегруженный метод для каждого типа а из них вызывать один метод, который будет, например, `long` принимать. Вызывать этот метод можно будет кастанув входящий тип к `long`. Второй вариант - метод, принимающий объектный тип, например `Number` - тоже, наверное, сработает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну если я правильно понял задачу, то например вот так. Принимаем на вход любое целочисленное значение и делаем с ним что-то не зависимо от типа(так как в long влезет и byte, и short, и int, и long):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte b = 5;
    short s = 6;
    int i = 7;
    long l = 8;
    method(b);
    method(s);
    method(i);
    method(l);

}

public static void method(long i){
    i++;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно в метод передать строку, а её в методе преобразовать в целочисленный тип

```
class Ideone
    {
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
             number("132");
        }

        private static void number(String a){
            System.out.print(Long.valueOf(a) * 2);
        }
    }
```